# How to inner join table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

i have table 

`Patient_Detail` that has  **id , name , check_in_id , check_out_id** 
.
`Check_Out` has  **Check_Out_ID , Illness_ID , Check_Out_Date.**
`Check_In` has  **Check_In_ID , Illness_ID , Check_In_Date .**
`Illness`has  **Illness_ID , Illness_Name .**
 but the problem is i don know how to join the `illness_Name` by `Check_out` table.

```
USE PantienDatabase

SELECT Name,Check_in,Illness_name,Check_out_ID FROM Check_In AS CI
INNER JOIN Patient_Detail AS P 
ON CI.Check_In_ID = P.Check_In_ID 
INNER JOIN Illness AS I 
ON I.IllnessID  =CI.illness_ID
INNER JOIN 
Check_Out AS CO
ON CO.Check_Out_ID = P.Check_out_ID
```

Comment: Despite all the typos the query looks fine. Whats the problem exactly?

Comment: the problem is, in `Check_out ` table have stored ** Illness_id ** and it could be different from table `Check_in`,so I want to join ** Illness_Name ** by ** Illness_id ** from data stored `Check_out ` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the same table twice and use aliases for the selected columns:

```
SELECT Name, Check_in,
       II.Illness_name AS Illness_name_in,
       IO.Illness_name AS Illness_name_out,
       Check_out_ID
FROM Check_In AS CI
INNER JOIN Patient_Detail AS P ON CI.Check_In_ID = P.Check_In_ID 
INNER JOIN Illness AS II ON II.IllnessID = CI.illness_ID
INNER JOIN Check_Out AS CO ON CO.Check_Out_ID = P.Check_out_ID
INNER JOIN Illness AS IO ON IO.IllnessID = CO.illness_ID
```